# configure oracle sql developer for hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to configure Oracle SQL Developer version 4.1.3.20 for accessing Hive.
I am following the instructions here:
https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/entry/oracle_sql_developer_data_modeler

1. I downloaded Cloudera_HiveJDBC41_2.5.15.1040
2. I extracted the jar files in the SQL Developer path:
   C:\Data\Projects\sqldeveloper
   [path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsPe4.jpg)
3. I open SQL Developer and add all jar files in Third Party JDBC
4. I close and reopen sqldeveloper
5. I still don't get the hive tab in new db connection

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Go back to that Oracle blog and read again the part that says "_Note: you will get an error when attempting to open a Hive connection in SQL Developer if you use a different JDBC version. Ensure you use JDBC4 and **not JDBC41**._" Then look closely at the label **HiveJDBC41** in the name of the driver you installed. Then start thinking hard.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter hi there, I don't see the "Hive" tab even after installing correct version of jdbc driver

Comment: @taiko this question is 4 years old, I have no idea how the current SQL Developer and the current Hive drivers fare together...

Answer (score 1):

Download:

> sqldeveloper-4.1.3.20.78-x64.zip

and try again.